# How to create a function with return type map<>?

Tags: c++, function, dictionary, return

Fairly straightforward question. I have a map that I wish to initialize by calling a function like so:

`map<string, int> myMap;`

`myMap = initMap( &myMap );`

```
map<string, int> initMap( map<string, int> *theMap )
{
    /* do stuff... */
```

However, the compiler is moaning. What's the solution to this?

**EDIT 1:**

I'm sorry, but I screwed up. The code was correctly written with `*theMap`, but when I posted the question, I failed to notice that I had omitted the `*`. So to answer the comment, the error message I get is:

`1>Roman_Numerals.cpp(21): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'`

which is thrown at

`map<char, int> initMap( map<char, int> *numerals );`

using VC++ 2010 Express and the same error again when I define the function.

Comment: What is the error message the compiler tells you?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Either do:

```
map<string, int> myMap;
initMap( myMap );

void initMap( map<string, int>& theMap )
{
    /* do stuff in theMap */
}
```

or do:

```
map<string, int> myMap;
myMap = initMap(  );

map<string, int> initMap()
{
    map<string, int> theMap;
    /* do stuff in theMap */
    return theMap;
}
```

i.e. let the function initialise the map you give it, or take the map the function gives you. You're doing both (without a `return` statement too!)

I'd go for the first option.

Answer (score 8):

It's probably complaining because you're passing the address of the map, but your function accepts the map by value.

You might want something more like this:

```
void initMap(map<string, int>& theMap)
{
    /* do stuff...*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I actually rewrote my code incorrectly. It contained the map<> *theMap, I just left the pointer out in the code I wrote here ><

Answer (score 4):

The canonical solution is just

```
std::map<std::string, int> initMap();
// ...
std::map<std::string, int> myMap = initMap();
```

Why the tricky attempt to use an input parameter for a return value? Performance? Modern compilers don't care. In fact, not constructing an empty map will be slightly faster.

Answer (score 3):

You should accept a pointer or preferably a reference to the map. You could also return a reference for convenience:

```
map<string, int>& initMap( map<string, int>& theMap )
...
// Call initMap
map<string, int> my_map;
initMap(my_map);
```

Answer (score 1):

why not do void initMap(map& theMap), instead of making so many copies of the map?

Answer (score 1):

`&myMap` is a pointer to a map object, while the argument `theMap` is a map object.

Two solutions:

Change `myMap = initMap( &myMap );` to `myMap = initMap( myMap );`.

or

Change `map<string, int> initMap( map<string, int> theMap )` to `map<string, int> initMap( map<string, int> * theMap )`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the game but:
I would guess from the error message that you're missing out

```
#include <map>
```

at the top of your code. So the compiler doesn't know that map is supposed to be a template, and it consequently gets confused by the angle brackets which follow.

Answer (score -1):

```
 void initMap(map<String,int> &Map)
 {
   //Do something
 }
```

Comment: Could you expand this answer, add an explanation what is does / why it works?

Comment: you are passing a reference of map to the init function.

Comment: Neither is the return value corresponds to a `map<K,T>` as what OP asks. Don't post gibberish things, please.